# Adding up fractions in PHP

Tags: php, rounding, floating-accuracy

I would like to create a loop that keeps adding a set fraction, here in my example 1/3, and which later I can check against for matches with integer values.

Obviously when php adds 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 the result is 0.9999999, so i thought I could use the occasional round to help me, but this isn't working either.

The idea that I had would be that .333 + .333 becomes .666 and that if rounded that would become .667, then + .333 and the result is 1. However round only seems to work, for me, if the number of digits actually decreases. so round (0.666, 3) remains 0.666

```
<?php
    $denom = 3;
    $frac = 1/$denom;
    $frac = round($frac,3);

    $value = 0;
    $max =24;
    for($f = 1; $f <= $max; $f++){
    echo "old value is now at ".$value.".<br/>";
    $value = $value+$frac;
    echo "value is now at ".$value.".<br/>";
    $value = round($value,3);
    echo "rounded value is now at ".$value.".<br/>";
    $valueArray[$f] = $value;
    //and here for ease of testing....
    if (($value==1)OR ($value==2)OR ($value==3)OR ($value==4)OR ($value==5)OR ($value==6)OR ($value==7)OR ($value==8)){
         echo "match!<br/>";
    }else{
        echo "no match!<br/>";
    }
    }


?>
```

Am I going about this in a totally stupid way?

Accuracy when the value is not an integer is not needed, just that it can == with integers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to round the values...

```
$i = 1/3;

echo $i . PHP_EOL;
echo 3*$i . PHP_EOL;
echo $i+$i+$i . PHP_EOL;

// prints:
// 0.33333333333333
// 1
// 1
```

Comment: if you save $i as a variable it is not the same as 1/3, see the warning float precision in the manual, http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#warn.float-precision

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to handle rationals accurately (ones that cannot be represented in the limited precision IEEE754 data types), you should *store* them as rationals.

In other words, get yourself a class that can handle a type `{numerator, denominator}` (both integers) and performs the arithmetic you need on them.

That way, the value will *stay* accurate through to the end point, where you can either print out the rational *as* a rational or convert it to decimal with only one level of conversion "error" rather than *many* of them being accumulated.